# Perforce remote depot

Tags: build, perforce, depot

I start with explaining the situation.
I have a server "A" where I submit official versions of my code, and a machine "M" where I generate daily builds, but sometimes I generate specific versions for my customers those I don't submit them into the server "A". So I create another server "B" where the programmers can submit them.

Now I want to regroup specific and official versions in the same server "B" and let the machine "M" get all code sources from this server.

Any idea how to do that??

NB: some peoples suggest to me to use Remote Depot, but I don't know what it the impact of this and how this can use it.

Comment: Have you considered a single server with depots A and B instead of individual servers? (That may not be feasible, of course, but it should be considered since it is often the best solution.) Otherwise, a remote depot will let the build machine go to a single source to fetch files at the cost of some resources on B (storage and some bandwidth between servers)

Comment: thanks William for your response. actually, there is two reasons why I should use a separate servers, the first one is that my BOSS wants to let server A clean without any adding or removing depots. the second is that I want regroup specific and official versions in the same depots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good place to get started learning about Remote Depot functionality: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/03_superuser.html#1065679

Comment: Thanks Brayan. I have seen this documentation before but I'm steel confused about what is the best practice in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

A remote depot is a one way data pipe from one server to another.  It sounds like it would be effective to move work from A to B.

If you want to keep all the data on one server, you can use Perforce directory structure, branching, and access control to organize and manage all the code.  That's a bit of a project to set up but might be worth it in the long run.

Comment: thank you p4-randall,
I created a remote depot and a local depot where I integrate the remote depot contents.